# python cv2 array to numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

I try to convert cv2 image array with multi lines, to single line one array!
Here is my code:

```
im =[]
img = cv2.imread('.jpg',0)

 for i in img :

   im.append(np.array(i))

 print (im)
```

I have this result : 
[array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255], dtype=uint8), array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]

But I need one line array:
['0', '0', '0', '255', '255', '255', '255', '254', '255', '255', '253', '255', '254', '255', '254', '255', '254', '254', '255', '255', '255', '255', '255', '255', '255', '255', '253', '253........]

What I'm doing wrong ?! Maybe there is some basic functions to convert from cv2 array to single array ?

Comment: What did you expect when adding a numpy-array to a list with append? This is basic python and basic numpy! I recommend the numpy docs (array-creation, flatten, ...). I also wonder why you want to do this (as it will be hard to process later).

Comment: Yes sure, its was a mistake, I mean - "im = np.array", because I need one line array for the next manipulations ! I need 2D array after, with numpy.array(array, ndmin=2).T

Comment: You are appending an *array*, not the *values* of the array. So your list `im` will be composed of multiple `numpy` arrays. There is another `numpy` method to append just the values instead of the array: `.extend()`. So `im.extend(i)` would do what you were expecting. However the answer with `hstack()` is far more efficient (doesn't require looping through your array in python), so you should definitely go with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
newarray = np.hstack(img)
print (newarray)
```

Comment: This is a good way to complete the task OP wanted to do, but could you provide a little more explanation to the answer and maybe link some documentation so OP could get a better grasp on why this is preferred?